# DPKG error: uninstall percona xtradb server 5.7

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, percona

Trying to uninstall percona, as I broke installation. No luck:

```
>$ sudo apt remove percona-xtradb-cluster-server-5.7
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  percona-xtradb-cluster-server-5.7
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 23 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 104 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 179533 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing percona-xtradb-cluster-server-5.7 (5.7.20-29.24-0ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: error processing package percona-xtradb-cluster-server-5.7 (--remove):
 installed percona-xtradb-cluster-server-5.7 package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 percona-xtradb-cluster-server-5.7
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

apt remove/purge/--force, nothing helps.

Removal with dpkg produces same:

```
sudo dpkg --remove  percona-xtradb-cluster-server-5.7
(Reading database ... 179533 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing percona-xtradb-cluster-server-5.7 (5.7.20-29.24-0ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: error processing package percona-xtradb-cluster-server-5.7 (--remove):
 installed percona-xtradb-cluster-server-5.7 package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 percona-xtradb-cluster-server-5.7
```

What is weird... I can start, stop, restart process with no issues:

```
sudo systemctl status mysql
● mysql.service - LSB: Start and stop the mysql (Percona XtraDB Cluster) daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql; generated)
   Active: active (exited) since Tue 2018-06-26 00:21:05 CEST; 31min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 5500 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysql start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

lip 26 00:21:05 tkojemile systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start and stop the mysql (Percona XtraDB Cluster) daemon...
lip 26 00:21:05 tkojemile systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start and stop the mysql (Percona XtraDB Cluster) daemon.
```

Also dpkg-query shows I assume - rH (removed|Half-installed):

```
dpkg-query -l percona-xtradb-cluster-server-5.7
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                          Version                     Architecture                Description
+++-=============================================-===========================-===========================-===============================================================================================
rH  percona-xtradb-cluster-server-5.7             5.7.20-29.24-0ubuntu2       amd64                       Percona XtraDB Cluster database server binaries
```

Anyone have idea how to uninstall/reinstall? I'm lack of options today...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You will probably have more help on [ubuntu.se] or [unix.se] since this installation question is not really related to databases.

Comment: You have bumped into an Ubuntu bug I am afraid (I think you have found this already) https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/percona-xtradb-cluster-5.7/+bug/1771869 - looks like there might be a solution soon

Comment: @percona-lorraine: yes... unfortunately no solution yet. Open and post-install script... no clue still, neither for me, nor them seems. Thanks guys